# iphone - how to communicate with labels (navigation based app with storyboard)

Tags: iphone, class, uilabel, storyboard, viewcontroller

I am making an app using a Navigation Controller, which I've set up like this:

0-Navigation Controller -> 1-View Controller (Root View)

1-View Controller (Root View) -> 2-View Controller (with class SubViewController) #1

1-View Controller (Root View) -> 2-View Controller (with class SubViewController) #2

1-View Controller (Root View) -> 2-View Controller (with class SubViewController) #3

1-View Controller contains a Text Field, `UILabel`, and 3 Buttons:
button #1 goes to 2-ViewController #1, #2 to #2, #3 to #3, using `segue`'s (push) for the connections between the buttons and viewcontrollers.

If this isnt clear, I'll explain: If you press button #1 in 1-ViewController, you go to SubViewController #1.

**Now where I'm getting stuck:**
 I want to communicate with a label in the SubViewController, but I can't draw a blue line (CTRL drag) from that UILabel to anywhere... (except the ViewController, which then gives the option: view, which doesn't seem what I need, I think).

**What I want to happen:**
 The user enters data in the textfield in 1-ViewController, which then is displayed in the `UILabel` in the chosen 2-SubViewController.

**How can I do this?**

EDIT:

It seems that my Assistant Editor was set to Manual instead of Automatic. After switching back, I was able of dragging lines.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do it manually:

add an `IBOutlet` for the `UILabel` in the `UIViewController` that should handle the label:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
{
IBOutlet UILabel *artistLabel;
IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;

}

@property (nonatomic, readonly) IBOutlet UILabel *artistLabel;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;
```

you'll now have the option in Interface Builder to drag from your label to the corresponding  `UIViewController`.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the explanation, but I still can't drag from my label to anywhere... If you want to, I've uploaded my XCode project here: http://speedy.sh/aKmcS/StoryboardApp1.zip

Comment: Oh wow. I just figured out that my Assist editor was somehow set to Manual... I switched it to Automatic and I can drag lines now, hahaha, what a stupid error! This fixes my error!